# Problema con Ajax Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

En un proyecto que estoy, utilizan lo siguiente para su search bar: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Tengo que hacer una modificación por sobre ese .js, básicamente por cuestiones de accesibilidad necesito que la caja de sugerencias al escribir en el search se mantenga abierta a menos que de click en alguna parte de la página. El motivo es porque por ejemplo usando un iPhone al escribir y darle en Hecho al teclado, cambia el focus y se cierran las sugerencias, lo cual no permite que el VoiceOver lea las sugerencias sin tener que reabrir la caja, y esto para una persona ciega puede ser complicado.

En desktop, si se usa tabulación debería pasar a otro elemento sin cerrar la caja de sugerencias, a menos que de click, pero actualmente tabular cierra la caja.

Gracias de antemano.